# How to check if user shared website (Facebook)? Is it possible?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently writing a website and I need some help about facebook integration.
I need a function (PHP or JS, both will help) that can check if a given user shared my website,
and I couldn’t find out how to write one.
Could you please point me at the right direction?

Answer (score 7):

First you have to load the Facebook SDK right after your  tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId                : "YOUR APP ID",
      status               : true, // check login status
      cookie               : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml                : false,  // parse XFBML
      perms                : 'read_stream',
      access_token         : "USER ACCESS TOkEN",
      frictionlessRequests : true
    });
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
```

Then you can use the callback function to do what you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function shareOnFacebook() {
    FB.ui(
      {
        method        : 'feed',
        display       : 'iframe',
        name          : 'name',
        link          : 'http://www.linktoshare.com',
        picture       : 'http://www.linktoshare.com/images/imagethumbnail.png',
        caption       : 'txt caption',
        description   : 'txt description',
        access_token  : 'user access token'
      },
      function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {

          // HERE YOU CAN DO WHAT YOU NEED
          alert('OK! User has published on Facebook.');

        } else {
          //alert('Post was not published.');
        }
      }
    );
  }
</script>
```

Then you should use it like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="shareOnFacebook();">Share on facebook</a>
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that you need to instantiate the SDK to use these features... Important point...

Comment: You must be careful with this, remember it is running on client side, an user could execute a function or something like he already share when he really don't.

Answer (score 5):

Using the [JavaScript SDK, `FB.ui()` and the `feed` dialog,](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) you can prompt your users to share a URL on Facebook.  This dialog provides a callback function so that you can tell if the post was made successfully.
<sub>Code sample lifted from the above link...</sub>

```
 var obj = {
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
};

function callback(response) {
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
}

FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

This is the easiest way to accomplish what you need.
It will not, however, allow you to test if someone shared your website's URL outside of your `feed` dialog.

---

A more complex alternative not requiring the dialog callback could be accomplished by utilizing the `read_stream` permission.  Once you have that permission, you can scan the users past posts to see if he has *ever* shared your website on his wall...

Keep in mind that this will not work if the user shared your website on some one else's wall or on a page...